# SQL multiple innerjoins with same ID

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

There's different types of boxes, and im trying to make a table collecting all "boxes".

Database Structure:

```
box table
box_id .. .. .. .. .. 

b_text table
tex_id  .. .. .. ..  fk_b_id

b_image table
ima_id .. .. .. .. . fk_b_id
```

Sql:

```
SELECT * FROM box
INNER JOIN b_image ON box.box_id = b_image.fk_b_id
INNER JOIN b_text ON box.box_id = b_text.fk_b_id
```

What I want:

```
1 text1  evenmoretext  
2 text2  evenmoretext
3 image1 evenmoretext imageurl  placement
4 text3  evenmoretext 
5 image2 evenmoretext imageurl  placement
```

I'm trying to match fk_b_id from all the different tables with the box id from box table.

note* the tables have different fields, which is probably causing a lot of trouble?

This doesn't work when I put on more than 1 INNER JOIN. Can someone please explain me why, and /or tell me a solution

Comment: Please show sample data for the tables in your question.

Comment: You mean underneath my title "What I want;" ?

Comment: The "what you want" is the _output_, but we need to see the _input_ also.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean by the input, I'm very new in this. What exactly do you need to understand the problem?

Comment: I edited the post before, removing the php tag, as there is no php code in the question, only sql. Please don't abuse the tags, some people, like me, search for tags to help people asking questions for that specific tag. I searched php and find this question, purely about sql. and it's annoying.

Comment: Show us what data is contained in your tables.

Comment: In both your join statements you join on box.box_id = bla. But in your description of the box table, you call the field [id], not [Box_id].

Comment: Oh, Thank you, simply writing mistake on here, it's box_id in my database.